# Epson WF-2830 scanner not detected

Tags: scanner

I have an Epson WF-2830. I have installed the Epson `imagescan` app from http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/du/02/DriverDownloadInfo.do?LG2=EN&CN2=&DSCMI=124529&DSCCHK=486c7cbdc48f28f18c8e55472362893da954bc02. However, when I run `imagescan` it does not find the scanner. It is not a network issue, since my Android phone (which is in the same network) can successfully scan from the printer. Any ideas?